# What happens if my RecyclerView adapter is reinitialized several times?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, custom-adapter

I have some recycler view code in a function that gets called several times as bluetooth devices are scanned. My code is working but I am wondering what unseen effects are occurring from having my recycler view initialization code in a function that gets repeated a lot? I eventually want to update the list rather than replace it via `notifyDataSetChanged()` but I am unsure how to do that with my current code structure. Any help would be appreciated!

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission", "NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun displayDevices(
        scannedDevicesStrings: TreeSet<String>,
        deviceMap: HashMap<String, String>
    ) {
        
        val sortedDeviceMap = deviceMap.toSortedMap()

        Log.d(TAG, "displayDevices: ${sortedDeviceMap.entries}")

        // Set linear layout manager for the widget.
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
        binding.recyclerviewDevices.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

        // Specify an adapter.
        listAdapter = CustomAdapter(scannedDevicesStrings.toList(), sortedDeviceMap, bluetoothManager)
        binding.recyclerviewDevices.adapter = listAdapter

        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        // Notify the view to update when data is changed.
        if ( binding.recyclerviewDevices.isAttachedToWindow) {
            binding.progressBarCyclic.visibility = GONE
        }
    }
```

This code calls my `CustomAdapter()` class which looks like this:

```
class CustomAdapter(
    private val treeSet: List<String>,
    private var hashMap: SortedMap<String, String>,
    private val bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_list_item)
        val listLayout: FrameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.item_layout)
        val context: Context = view.context
        val textView2: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_list_item_address)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.text_device_row_item, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val deviceList = hashMap.keys.toList()
        val macAddressList = hashMap.values.toList()
        holder.textView.text = deviceList.elementAt(position)
        holder.textView2.text = macAddressList.elementAt(position)
        val selectedDeviceString = deviceList.elementAt(position).toString()
        val selectedDevice = bluetoothManager.adapter.getRemoteDevice(hashMap[selectedDeviceString])
        val sharedPreferences = holder.context.getSharedPreferences("mSharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
            with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
                putString("selectedDeviceString", selectedDevice.toString())
                apply()
            }
        holder.listLayout.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(holder.context, DeviceActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("btDevice", selectedDevice)
            intent.putExtra("btDeviceName", selectedDeviceString)
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("loadedFrom", "loadedFromCustomAdapter").apply()
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("selectedDeviceName", selectedDeviceString).apply()
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("selectedDeviceString", selectedDevice.toString()).apply()
            holder.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = treeSet.size
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a new adapter makes the `RecyclerView` reinitialise itself, and it'll create all the `ViewHolder`s again, etc. You'd want to avoid that really. This is generally how you'd make it update:

```
class CustomAdapter(
    private var data: List<Thing>
    ...
) {

    fun setData(data: List<Thing>) {
        // store the data and do any other setup work
        this.data = data
        // make sure the RecyclerView updates to show the new data
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

Then you just need to keep a reference to the adapter when you first create it in `onCreate` or whatever, and call `theAdapter.setData(newData)` whenever you get the new stuff. You're just setting up by creating an adapter to handle displaying your data in the list, and then you hand it data whenever it needs to update.

The actual "how things update" logic is in `setData` - it's the adapter's business how the adapter works internally, y'know? Right now it's the most basic `notifyDataSetChanged()` call, i.e. "refresh everything", but you could change that later - the outside world doesn't need to care about that though.

---

I noticed in `onBindViewHolder` you're doing this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val deviceList = hashMap.keys.toList()
    val macAddressList = hashMap.values.toList()
```

That function runs *every time* a `ViewHolder` needs to display some new information (just before it scrolls onto the screen, basically) so you're creating a lot of lists whenever you scroll. Really you should do that once, when the data is set - derive your lists from the source and keep them around:

```
class CustomAdapter(
    initialData: List<Thing> // not a var now - see init block
    ...
) {

    // these might need to be lateinit since you're init-ing through a function
    private var data: List<Thing>
    private var deviceList: List<String>
    private var macAddressList: List<String>

    init {
        setData(initialData)
    }

    fun setData(data: List<Thing>) {
        // Now you're storing the data and deriving the other lists
        // You might not even need to store the 'data' object if you're not using it?
        this.data = data
        deviceList = data.keys.toList()
        macAddressList = data.values.toList()

        // make sure the RecyclerView updates to show the new data
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

So now `setData` takes some source data, derives the lists you need to use and stores those, and calls the update function. Because that setup has to be done, you need to call this function every time the source data is set - including when you first create the adapter. That's why the data parameter in the constructor isn't a `var`, it's just used in the initialisation, passed to the `setData` call.

Or alternatively, don't pass any data in the constructor at all - just create the adapter, and immediately call `setData` on it. Initialise the variables to `emptyList()` etc, and then you don't need to handle the "setup at construction time" case at all!

---

Just another couple of tips - I don't know what `treeSet` is for, but you're using its size in `getItemCount`. You shouldn't do that, it should usually reflect the size of the data set you're actually displaying, which is the contents of `hashSet` - when you get a `position` in `onBindViewHolder`, you're looking up an element in `hashSet`, not `treeSet`, so that should be your source for the number of items

The other thing is, all that stuff in `onBindViewHolder`... you're doing a lot of setup work that should really only happen when the item is actually clicked. Usually you'd set up the click listener once, in `onCreateViewHolder`, and when binding you'd set a field on the viewholder telling it which `position` it's currently displaying. If the click listener fires, *then* you can look up the current `position` in the data, create `Intent`s, etc

Even if you don't move that into the VH, at least move the setup code into the `onClickListener` so it doesn't run every time a new item scrolls into view. That `sharedPreferences` bit is especially a problem - that gets overwritten every time a new item is bound (and they can be bound when they're still off-screen) so it probably isn't set to what you expect

Comment: Oh wow! That's a lot of really great information. Thanks for taking the time to answer! I'm going to start updating my code while trying to apply what you suggest.

Comment: So, there should only ever be one source for the data and that source of data should be provided when the adapter is initialized in `onCreate()` and then updated via the `setData()` function within the adapter, correct?

Comment: @DylonJaynes it's more like, you have your list UI widget (the RecyclerView) and you have a component that takes data and makes the UI display it (the Adapter). So you create that adapter component once, plug it into the recyclerview (and all the other setup), and now you have a thing that can display data. Then you just make it so you can pass data to the adapter, and it'll make the recycler update and display it. The data source can be anything (like a network call or database lookup) - it's nothing to do with the adapter. You just hand it some data to display whenever you want it to update

Comment: @DylonJaynes so like I was saying, you don't even need to pass any data into the constructor if you don't want! Initialise your data lists as empty lists etc, and the ``RecyclerView`` will show nothing. You can give it some data to display at any point, by calling ``setData``

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you mean now! So basically, it doesn't really matter if the data is initialized before the adapter is created because it's just a tool to take data and adapt it for the view. At any point, I can give it data if I include a function to allow for it.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I was able to implement the majority of what you suggested all except for moving the click listener to `onCreateViewHolder()` as I couldn't quite figure out how to do it, but it still works great!

Comment: @DylonJaynes No worries! Don't worry too much about the click listener thing - a lot of people create and set a new one in ``onBindViewHolder``, it's not doing any work until it's run at least. But the basic idea is that a `ViewHolder` has a `View` that holds the layout for an item, and a `RecyclerView` creates a handful of those, and *recycles* them to display different items (which is what `onBindViewHolder` is - here's a VH, set it up for this position). So you'd just create a click listener on the VH's `itemView` instead when creating it, and set item data on the VH when you bind to it

Answer (score 1):

Setting the adapter multiple times should be avoided.  Doing so causes its scroll position to be lost and reset to the top, and causes it to have to reinflate all of its views and ViewHolders.  Instead, you should update the model your adapter points at and notifyDataSetChanged() on it (or better yet, use DiffUtil to update individual items).

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I have been trying to figure out why the scroll position kept jumping to the top so that makes a lot of sense. I will look into DiffUtil as I'm not sure what that is exactly.

Comment: @DylonJaynes DiffUtil compares two sets of data for an adapter and will check which items changed and issue an optimized set of notifyItemUpdated, notifyItemDeleted, and notifyItemAdded commands to the adapter.  It's more efficient than just telling it the entire data set updated.  https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil

Answer (score 0):

I finished updating my code and it works great! The data no longer jumps to the top when new data is added. Thought I would post the code for anyone who is interested.

Here is my adapter:

```
class CustomAdapter(
    private val bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var sortedMap = emptyMap<String, String>()
    private var deviceList = emptyList<String>()
    private var macAddressList = emptyList<String>()

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_list_item)
        val listLayout: FrameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.item_layout)
        val context: Context = view.context
        val textView2: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_list_item_address)
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun setData(sortedMap: SortedMap<String, String>) {
        this.sortedMap = sortedMap
        deviceList = sortedMap.keys.toList()
        macAddressList = sortedMap.values.toList()

        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.text_device_row_item, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.textView.text = deviceList.elementAt(position)
        holder.textView2.text = macAddressList.elementAt(position)

        holder.listLayout.setOnClickListener {
            val selectedDeviceString = deviceList.elementAt(position).toString()
            val selectedDevice = bluetoothManager.adapter.getRemoteDevice(sortedMap[selectedDeviceString])
            val sharedPreferences = holder.context.getSharedPreferences("mSharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return@setOnClickListener
            with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
                putString("selectedDeviceString", selectedDevice.toString())
                apply()
            }

            val intent = Intent(holder.context, DeviceActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("btDevice", selectedDevice)
            intent.putExtra("btDeviceName", selectedDeviceString)
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("loadedFrom", "loadedFromCustomAdapter").apply()
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("selectedDeviceName", selectedDeviceString).apply()
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("selectedDeviceString", selectedDevice.toString()).apply()
            holder.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = sortedMap.size
}
```

And the activity `onCreate()` code:

```
// Specify an adapter.
listAdapter = CustomAdapter(bluetoothManager)
binding.recyclerviewDevices.adapter = listAdapter
```

And my function that updates the data:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission", "NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun displayDevices(
        deviceMap: HashMap<String, String>
    ) {
        
        val sortedDeviceMap = deviceMap.toSortedMap()
        listAdapter.setData(sortedDeviceMap)

        Log.d(TAG, "displayDevices: ${sortedDeviceMap.entries}")

        // Notify the view to update when data is changed.
        if ( binding.recyclerviewDevices.isAttachedToWindow) {
            binding.progressBarCyclic.visibility = GONE
        }
    }
```